# How to set one button to show different results with pop ups? (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx

I'm making some program where I have input field and show result button (SRB). When I put some data in that input field and press SRB, I want to call pop up with some result.

For example:

- if I put 1-5 in the field and press SRB I want to call pop up with text "Hello"
- if I put 6-10 in the field and press SRB I want to call pop up with text "Bye"
- if I put "chel" in the field and press SRB I want to call pop up with text "Some Stuff"

So I want to call one pop up but force it to display different outputs.

How can I do that?

Here I tried to do that by calling different pop ups. But it turned off like
I put 1 - it calls popUp.fxml, which I don't want for numbers.

Here's my Controller

```
public class FirstQuestionController {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private TextField answerField;

    @FXML
    private Button nextButton;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {

        nextButton.setOnAction(event->{
            Calculations calculations = new Calculations();
            String answer = answerField.getText().trim();
            if (answer.contains("chel")) {
                calculations.ageResults(answer);
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                Parent root = null;
                try {
                    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/popUp.fxml"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                stage.initOwner(nextButton.getScene().getWindow());
                stage.showAndWait();
            } else {
                answer = answerField.getText()
                int age = Integer.parseInt(answer);
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                Parent root = null;
                try {
                    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/agePopUp.fxml"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                stage.initOwner(nextButton.getScene().getWindow());
                stage.showAndWait();
            }


        });

    }
}
```

Calculation class is for input checking purposes. If input field has 1-5, then it shows "Hello" result etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Regular Expressions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) to handle each case depending on the input :

```
if(answer.matches(".*chel.*"))
{
    // "Some stuff"
} else if(answer.matches("[1-5]"))
{
    // "Hello"
} else if(answer.matches("[6-9]|10"))
{
    // "Bye"
} else
{
    //none of the above
}
```